# Gravity of the accelerated particle in General relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, acceleration

Suppose heavy particle or body ("billiard ball") is accelerated with very thin and very rigid (not absolutely rigid) rod of infinitesimal (not zero) mass ("cue stick")

[image]

Acceleration is constant in relativity sense, i.e. hyperbolic motion in stationary reference frame. Mass of "particle" should be big enough to cause relativity effects. I.e. all parameters should cause the most simplistic situation, except some relativity effects should present.

What will be the additional non-Newtonian field and what it will look like?

How this can be calculated in General relativity?

Answer (score 3):

The closest I know of to this is the C-metric, which describes a pair of black holes accelerating away from each other. I couldn't find any nice articles on the Internet, but the C-metric is described in Chapter 14 of [Exact Space-Times in Einstein's General Relativity](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Space-Times-Einsteins-Relativity-Monographs-Mathematical-ebook/dp/B00AKE1W3U) by Jerry B. Griffiths, Jiří Podolský. You can find a [scan on Google books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SbZpFMOwhzMC&pg=PA258&lpg=PA258&dq=c-metric+relativity&source=bl&ots=nHOfz3g_V8&sig=D_caonF1yfWXRipocTFu4xYxIrQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=a-AiVJzqFarbsAS5joG4Bw&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=c-metric%20relativity&f=false).

Comment: Is it possible/reasonable to subtract effect of one of the holes? I would like one force be non-gravitational.

Comment: @SuzanCioc: don't know I'm afraid. I've never studied the C-metric. You should read up on it as I think the acceleration is caused by a strut not unlike you describe. It's actually a conical singularity, but it acts like a strut.